# CodeIgniter session: If the expiration time is greater than the refresh time, does it mean that it will never expire?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a question about the PHP framework CodeIgniter.

```php
$config['sess_expiration'] = 7200;
$config['sess_time_to_update'] = 300;
```

If the expiration time is greater than the refresh time, does it mean that it will never expire?

I dont't understand what's going on here.

```
sess_time_to_update
```

Answer (score 0):

`session_expiration` is the number of seconds you would like the session to last. If you would like a non-expiring session. For example if you configure it with 7200, your session will be available 7200 seconds from session creation

`sess_time_to_update` is how often the session class will regenerate itself and create a new session ID. In your case if you configure it to 300 seconds, your session ID will be regenerated every 300 seconds with the same content